# Azure Function Can't bind parameter 'messageReceiver' to type 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver'

Tags: azure-functions

Having upgraded to Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus v5.2.0 MessageReceiver no longer works.

```
MessageReceiver messageReceiver
```

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
> 'BrunelWMSServiceBus'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind
> parameter 'messageReceiver' to type
> 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver'.

`MessageReceiver` is still supported according to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.core.messagereceiver?view=azure-dotnet) but it no longer works in the run-time. I've seen references to parameter naming but `messageReceiver` is apparently ok.

```
ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions
```

works but MUST be called `messageActions` or it will fail to bind too. Just wondering whether to stop using `MessageReceiver` and use `ServiceBusMessageActions` instead.

Comment: You can refer to similar issue on GitHub: [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'XXX'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind parameter 'messageReceiver' to type 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver'.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/25375#issue-1055673915)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not added to the specs yet, but obviously IMessageReceiver shouldn't be used any longer as it belongs to Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus library which is deprecated and not referenced by Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus SDK anymore. So ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions parameter is definitely the way to go now.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus#message-settlement