# Azure Functions V4 NET 6 Service Bus Trigger not fired

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, .net-6.0, azure-servicebus-queues

I just upgraded my Azure Functions to v4. I have a Service Bus Queue trigger to process the messages of a queue.
After I did the upgrade it is no more fired and I don't understand why and how to investigate.
The code is not changed from one version to another and I could not find any breaking change on this topic.
The log of the function does not show any error or execution and the messages are stuck in the queue without additional information.

This is my trigger:

```
public class IncomingQueueTrigger
{
    private string _body;
    private HttpResponseMessage response;
    private SignalErrorQueueItem _errorObj;
    private readonly short _maxTriesCount = 2;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public IncomingQueueTrigger(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    }

    [FunctionName("IncomingQueueTrigger")]
    public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%my_queue_name%", Connection = "my_connection_string")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage myQueueItem, string label, ServiceBusReceiver messageReceiver)
    {
        // my code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing locally the Function I got this error:
`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'IncomingQueueTrigger'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind parameter 'messageReceiver' to type 'Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceiver'.`
And searching on Google I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70034969/azure-function-cant-bind-parameter-messagereceiver-to-type-microsoft-azure-s) in which I understood that with the function update I have also to update the type of the message receiver:

`ServiceBusReceiver` => `ServiceBusMessageActions`

Now everything is back to work.

Thanks to HariKrishnaRajoli-MT for suggesting me to try to run the functions locally.

Comment: thanks! 
Just to be clear i had to chage the "Message message" param aswell, Complete params =>
ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, ServiceBusMessageActions messageReceiver

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you review the [Azure Functions Migration Document from `3.x` to `4.x`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process,azure-cli,v4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#migrating-from-3x-to-4x) for upgrading the runtime version of your function app.

Also, information on code changes when migrating the [.NET Core 3.1 to 6.0 - document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) and regarding how to update package references in Azure Functions when runtime version is migrated.

If it is not working locally, debug the function code and check or if it works locally and not working in the Azure, do the [remote debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/296869/how-to-remote-debugg-an-azure-function-that-we-tri.html) and also check this window in the Azure Function App Portal:

[image]

If the issue still persists, contact the Azure Support through mail (AzCommunity@Microsoft.com) by providing the Issue Description, Result/Error Screenshots and the troubleshooting steps you followed.

Comment: I didn't know I could run the functions locally. I have always used the remote debugging, but since I've started using DevOps Pipeline to publish the functions I have not been able anymore to remote debug. With this I found the problem. Thank you